# Why different ways of importing classes in Nestjs affect dependency injection？

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, abstract-class

I am developing NestJS project with typescript.
I'm trying to inject a class into the constructor, as follows:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    ...Some omitted content,
    private loginFactory: LoginFactory,
  ) {}
}
```

LoginFactory is a factory class, as follows:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginFactory {
  constructor(
    private readonly phoneLoginService: PhoneLoginService,
    private readonly verificationCodeLoginService: VerificationCodeLoginService,
  ) {}
}
```

Both the PhoneLoginService class and the VerificationCodeLoginService class inherit an abstract class called AbstractLoginService, as follows:

```
@Injectable()
export class PhoneLoginService extends AbstractLoginService {
  constructor(protected readonly userService: UserService) {
    super(userService);
  }
}
```

```
@Injectable()
export class VerificationCodeLoginService extends AbstractLoginService {
  constructor(protected readonly userService: UserService) {
    super(userService);
  }
}
```

The AbstractLoginService abstract class is as follows:

```
export abstract class AbstractLoginService<T extends LoginDto = LoginDto> {
  constructor(protected readonly userService: UserService) {}
  ...Some omitted content
}
```

My AuthModule content is as follows:

```
@Module({
  ...Some omitted content
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    PhoneLoginService,
    VerificationCodeLoginService,
    LoginFactory,
  ],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

My code worked fine until I recently cleaned up the file structure. Specifically, this is how I imported LoginFactory in AuthService:
`import { LoginFactory } from './login-factory.service';`
Since the above service classes are in the services directory, I added a new file named index.ts, which serves as a unified exit.Its contents are as follows:

```
export * from './abstract-login.service';
export * from './auth.service';
export * from './login-factory.service';
export * from './phone-login.service';
export * from './verificationCode-login.service';
```

At the same time, I changed the import method of the LoginFactory class in the AuthService class as follows:

```
import { LoginFactory } from './';
```

However, when I started the project again, I reported the following error:

```
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the LoginFactory (?, +). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [0] is available in the AuthModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is AuthModule a valid NestJS module?
- If dependency is a provider, is it part of the current AuthModule?
- If dependency is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AuthModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing dependency */ ]
  })
```

It looks like something is wrong with the injection of the LoginFactory class.But when I changed the way LoginFactory was imported in the AuthService class, everything went back to normal.Specifically, I changed the import method back as shown below:
`import { LoginFactory } from './login-factory.service';`
I'm guessing it might be a problem with the import order. But it's just speculation.
I would appreciate your help.

I tried to change the import method of the file little by little, and finally determined that the import method of LoginFactory affected the normal operation of the project

Answer (score 1):

When you use a barrel import (`./`, or something like `./auth`), you aren't importing *only* the necessary file from that related `index.ts` file, you are importing **all** of the exports from that file, and each file there is importing everything that it needs to as well. In this case, you are creating circular import statements on the files themselves. `auth.service` imports from `./` meaning it imports `auth.service`, `abstract-ogin.service`, `login-factory.service` and others. The fact that `auth.service` imports `auth.service` is already a red flag, but then if you look at `login-factory.service` and it *also* imports from `./` then it *also* imports `auth.service` and now you have a two part circular chain, and this can continue for as many files as you have.

*My* general rule for barrel files is that from *outside* the feature, it's fine to import from them, but from *inside* the feature, import from files directly. This helps separate what is the public and private API of the feature as well.

Comment: Thanks for your helping,this solved one of my big puzzles. Thank you so much.